# Highchart: Bubble heading is not showing if two bubbles intersect or comes near one another in Bubble chart

Tags: highcharts, bubble-chart

In Highcharts Bubblechart if i two bubbles comes near one another or intersect one another, the name on top of one bubble is not displaying.

Is there a way to display both the bubble names.

In this the notice the two bubbles in top right `enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/htb38096/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the `allowOverlap` property for data labels:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            allowOverlap: true,
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k23xLjmn/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bubble.dataLabels.enabled

Answer (score 0):

try this on `dataLabels`:

```
dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      useHTML: true,             
      style: { textShadow: 'none',fontSize: '10px',color:'black' },
      formatter: function() {
             return this.point.name;
      },
}
```